# python multiprocessing: write the results into multiple files

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm using python multiprocessing to deal with sequential rule mining. I want to write the results(a large amount of rules) into different files as one process corresponds to one file.

```
def work(conseq, proj, abs_min, minconf, db_dict, output):
    dic = fpgrowth_opt(proj, abs_min)
    for ant, sup in dic.items():
        count = db_dict[ant]
        conf = sup / count
        if conf >= minconf:
            with open(output, 'a') as f:
                rule = str(list(ant)) + ' ==> ' + str(conseq) + '  support: ' + str(sup) + '  conf: ' + str(conf) + '\n'
                f.write(rule)
            f.close()
```

So that's the method I will use for parallel running.
I try to use the starmap to implement the multiprocessing:

```
args = [(x, y, abs_min, minconf, database_dict) for (x, y) in projection.items()]
new_args = []
i = 0
for arg in args:
    if i < 4:
        l = list(arg)
        l.append(outputs+'/output'+str(i)+'.txt')
        new_args.append(tuple(l))
        i += 1
    else:
        i = 0
p.starmap(work, new_args)
p.close()
p.join()
```

But I got errors like this(in the middle the rule is not complete):

```
['12483', '12571'] ==> 12703  support: 68  conf: 0.5483870967741935
['12483', '10311', '12571'] ==> 12703  support: 55  conf: 0.8088235294117647
['12679'] ==> 12751  support: 100  conf: 0.05592841163310962
onf: 0.864406779661017
['12483', '12487', '12571'] ==> 12703  support: 60  conf: 0.6451612903225806
['12431', '12679'] ==> 12751  support: 81  conf: 0.680672268907563
['10315', '12571'] ==> 12703  support: 68  conf: 0.5666666666666667
```

I wonder how to make the process write to the corresponding output file correctly?

Comment: no need for `f.close()` . why do you think the problem is related to file writing?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried `starmap_async()` instead?

Comment: You only have 4 output files (output0.txt, output1.txt, output2.txt & output3.txt) but you have many processes concurrently writing to these files. Corruption is almost inevitable

Comment: @user56700 I tried, it also appeared the same problem

Comment: @AndyKnight I actually set the process number being 4. I want to make sure that each process takes care of one output file so that conflicts might be solved. But I can't find a way to do that with starmap(or any other map methods).

Comment: @balderman More precisely, I think the problem is when multiple processes write on one file, conflict happens.

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont know what your input data is, I cannot test this, but maybe it will give you an idea of, how to write to a file without corruption.

I store the information that the threads want to write in an in-memory data structure, which in this case is a Python list, and write the contents of the list to a file once all threads have joined.

Again, please note, I have not tested this, but I hope it might work.

```
import threading

global_lock = threading.Lock()
file_contents = []
threads = []

def work(conseq, proj, abs_min, minconf, db_dict):
    while global_lock.locked():
        continue
    dic = fpgrowth_opt(proj, abs_min)
    for ant, sup in dic.items():
        count = db_dict[ant]
        conf = sup / count
        if conf >= minconf:
            rule = str(list(ant)) + ' ==> ' + str(conseq) + '  support: ' + str(sup) + '  conf: ' + str(conf) + '\n'
            global_lock.acquire()
            file_contents.append(rule)
            global_lock.release()

args = [(x, y, abs_min, minconf, database_dict) for (x, y) in projection.items()]

for arg in args:
    t = threading.Thread(target=work, args=(arg,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

[thread.join() for thread in threads]

with open("outputfile.txt", "a+") as file:
    file.write('\n'.join([str(content) for content in file_contents]))
```

Comment: The OP is using multi-processing and therefore the threading.Lock() mechanism isn't helpful. Also, you're locking pre- and post-appending to a list which is inherently thread-safe

Comment: @AndyKnight with all that knowledge, you should write up an answer. :)

Comment: if only the OP would provide enough information I'd be more than happy to do that. As he has failed to provide a minimal working example that's impossible without guessing and that in itself isn't helpful to anyone

Comment: @AndyKnight While this is absolutely true, I do not see any comment to his question, where you tell him to provide more information. That would be a good place to start I guess.